# How to save Color Scheme in ppt application c# vsto

Tags: c#, vba, vsto, powerpoint, add-in

I want to know if it is possible to save the colors of a ppt document programatically using C# vsto ppt add-in. 
I have logic to save it for current document

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            pptApp = this.Application;
            pptApp.AfterNewPresentation += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.EApplication_AfterNewPresentationEventHandler(pptApp_AfterNewPresentation);
        }

private void pptApp_AfterNewPresentation(PowerPoint.Presentation pres)
        {
            AddTheme(pres);
        }

        private void AddTheme(PowerPoint.Presentation pres)
        {
            pres.ApplyTheme(theme);
            PowerPoint.ColorScheme myScheme = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide.ColorScheme;
            Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation.ColorSchemes.Add(myScheme);

            //????

        }
```

it's adding color scheme to presentation and color schemes in design tab.
When I choose other color scheme mine is disappearing from Design tab :( 
I need it to always be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String programfilesPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
            String msOfficePath = "Microsoft\\Templates\\Document Themes\\Test.thmx";
            String fullPath = Path.Combine(programfilesPath, msOfficePath);

            Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation.SaveCopyAs(fullPath);
```

This one works.

Answer (score 0):

The theme needs to be physically present on the users profile to be listed on the Design tab everytime. Save the theme in this location: 
"%AppData%\Microsoft\Templates\Document Themes"